# Can I clone my SSD to a partition on my HDD and disconnect it?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

So my SSD is dieing, and I've already made several backups of everything important (photo's, music, documents, etc.) on my computer. The good thing is, it's still under warranty so I can get a new one.

Now I have a bit of an issue. I don't want to send the computer store my SSD with all my data on it, so I want to completely wipe it before sending it, and it might possibly take more than a week or more for them to analyse it, and get me a new one.

So I came up with this plan:

I make a similar-sized partition on my hard disk drive (which is still working perfectly fine), and I clone my SSD to this partition. Then I magically set my computer up to boot from this drive, and if all goes well, I can use my computer temporary without SSD.

So my question is: *How do I accomplish this.. what software to use and how to set it up?*

I already tried this, but I'm very new to cloning drives etc. so I probably did something wrong (I reverted the changes and everything is back to normal). When I would boot windows from the partition, it'd say something like: Windows is unable to find a required drive.

Comment: basically: Set your Primary Disk to your HDD in BIOS, make the "Magic" Partition Bootable, make shure you have the right settings, that the SDD can be mirrored on the HDD. I have never tried to move a Disk only to a partition, but that way it works on whole disks.

Comment: @EGOrecords Could I maybe use my external drive (which doesn't have much on it, so I can temporarily store that somewhere else) for this purpose? Or only if I connect it via SATA and not USB? I found that I didn't have much success on this method with partitions so I could try that first. - Most software doesn't support disk to partition cloning, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: A normal Windows installation won't boot from a USB drive, although eSATA should work.

Comment: @Karan Why is that? I can boot Linux from a flash drive, why not Windows?

Comment: Don't ask me, ask Microsoft! :) Win8 Enterprise is the first to officially support [Windows To Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go).